# iTunes Match not downloading high bitrate version of songs

Tags: iphone, itunes, icloud, music, itunes-match

I have a playlist in iTunes that shows all my songs that are matched with iTunes Match but are lower than 256 kbps. What I do every once in a while, is delete all the songs in the playlist (I delete them from iTunes, but NOT from iTunes Match/iCloud, then download them again. This is supposed to download the 256 kbps copies that iTunes has of each song.

Lately though, I've noticed that when I delete and download these songs again, the version that is downloaded is exactly the same as the one I just deleted. Is this a new thing? Or is this just a bug?

Comment: it means the tracks have not been recognised by itunes and so it has uploaded your version in itunes match.... So when you download it again, it will only download the track uploaded and not the 256k version... To check you need to see the cloud status by track and you will see....

Comment: I already checked the iCloud status on these songs. They are marked as "Matched", NOT "Uploaded".

Comment: ok so it's weird.... Did you delete as well the files from the itunes library (not from itunes)... did you try from another computer to see which file is it downloading?

Comment: Yes I deleted the actual files from the iTunes Library, but not from iTunes Match. I didn't try another computer because I don't have a second computer setup with my iTunes Match account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to iTunes Match not working properly, I also noticed that I was unable to add new songs to my iTunes library. After searching online, I came across [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2566265?start=0&tstart=0), in which some of the posts recommend logging out and back in to your iTunes Store account. So, I did that, and both the iTunes Match problem and the add songs problem were fixed.

Although for some reason, unchecked songs still aren't downloading higher bitrate versions, so I haven't completely figured things out yet.